Main actor-isolated static method issue
I have just installed Xcode16 beta, enabled strict concurrency + Swift version 6 SWIFT_STRICT_CONCURRENCY = complete;
SWIFT_VERSION = 6.0;
I am maintaining (and developing) a SwiftUI macOS app for years, and ahead of installing Xcode16 beta strict concurrency was enabled in Swift5. I am extending the Commands by the Commands protocol and now it will not compile in version 6 of Swift. And I don't know how to solve the issue? Xcode issue this error:
/Users/thomas/GitHub/RsyncUI/SwiftUI.Commands:6:51 Main actor-isolated static method '_makeCommands(content:inputs:)' cannot be used to satisfy nonisolated protocol requirement

The code which cause the issue is like this:
import SwiftUI

struct ExecuteCommands: Commands {
    @FocusedBinding(\.aborttask) private var aborttask
    var body: some Commands {
        CommandMenu("Abort") {
            Abborttask(aborttask: $aborttask)
        }
    }
}

struct Abborttask: View {
    @Binding var aborttask: Bool?

    var body: some View {
        Button {
            aborttask = true
        } label: {
            Label("Abort task", systemImage: "play.fill")
        }
        .keyboardShortcut("k", modifiers: [.command])
    }
}

struct FocusedAborttask: FocusedValueKey {
    typealias Value = Binding<Bool>
}

extension FocusedValues {
    var aborttask: FocusedAborttask.Value? {
        get { self[FocusedAborttask.self] }
        set { self[FocusedAborttask.self] = newValue }
    }
}


Submit a bug report

bug report is submitted
